# Structuring vue js files

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

This is probably a very basic question so bear with me I come from a jquery background and I'm a bit confused on how to structure code in Vue.

I have a laravel project set up with vue.js so one app.js file.
Let's say I have a set of directives in that app.js for registering a user :

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: { 
        errors: [],
        email:null,
        first_name:null,
        last_name:null,
        ...
    },
    methods:{
            register: function (e) {
//Do stuff
}
});
```

Now what if I now want to write code for another page, let's say a crud application to list the users where should I write the Vue code ?
I guess I could add to my app.js file but I will soon end up with a huge app.js file and I do not want to expose methods in pages that do not require them.

What is the correct way of doing this, I guess there must be some kind of routing going on somewhere ?

Comment: don't use `app.js ` plz check this https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/02/05/vue-laravel-crud/

Comment: you mean keep one app.js file but use components for the different functions ?

Comment: `app.js` is think like a `main.js` file in your project. using for global purpose. individual script you need to write each component

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, you can make use of components for implementing different pages ad even inside a page you can then make child components.
Each component consists of the template i.e., HTML code, script, and its respective style.
Making use of components makes the code more maintainable, reusable, and understandable.
You can check this link for understanding more about the components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

For routing, there is an official router for Vuejs which is Vue router. You can find more on the router on https://router.vuejs.org/.